# Why executor is not running out of available threads when its threads ends up with exceptions?

Tags: java, multithreading, threadpool, executorservice, threadpoolexecutor

In the following scenario my task throws an exception. I was excepting that after one request my pool would not be able to process any further requests but it is not happening. How does thread pool behaves in this scenario?  How communication of exception happens from Pool thread to main application thread?

```
public class CallableClass implements Callable<String> {

    @Override
    public String call() throws Exception {
        throw new RuntimeException();
    }

}

class Test {
      ExecutorService executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(1);

      public void execute(){  
         try {
            System.out.println(executor);
            Future<String> future = executor.submit(new Task());
            System.out.println(executor);

            future.get();
        }catch(Exception e) {
           System.out.println(executor);
           e.printStackTrace();
        }
     }

  }
```

Answer (score 1):

You could check it out by printing the name of the currently executing thread:

```
@Override
public String call() throws Exception {
    System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName());
    ...
}
```

> 1. How does thread pool behaves in this scenario?

The worker notifies the executor service about the exception occurred when it was working. But there is no reason to remove that worker from the `ThreadPoolExecutor#workers` set. It will continue its work if there is a need.

You shouldn't see any failures of the executor service. It's going to replace an invalid worker (or a thread) with a valid one if something wrong happens:

> If any thread terminates due to a failure during execution prior to shutdown, a new one will take its place if needed to execute subsequent tasks.
>
> <sup>[ExecutorService.newFixedThreadPool(int)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Executors.html#newFixedThreadPool-int-) [JDK 9]</sup>

---

> 2. How communication of exception happens from Pool thread to main application thread?

Any exception thrown from a `Callable#call` is being wrapped by an `ExecutionException` and is popped up to the caller:

> @throws `ExecutionException` if the computation threw an exception
>
> <sup>[Future.get()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Future.html#get--) [JDK 9]</sup>

An example of cheching whether `ExecutionException#getCause` is a `RuntimeException` instance:

```
} catch (ExecutionException e) { 
    Throwable cause = e.getCause();
    if (cause != null && cause instanceof RuntimeException) {
        System.out.println("A RuntimeException was thrown.");
    }
}
```

Comment: Hello Andrew, I updated the Task code as: class Task implements Callable<String>{
 @Override
 public String call() throws Exception {
     System.out.println(Thread.currentThread()+">>>>>>>>>>>>>>"+Thread.currentThread().getName());

  throw new RuntimeException();
  
 }
} But for every request it prints the same thread name. It means same worker is being used repeatedly even after an exception while executing a previous task.

Comment: "Any exception thrown from a Callable#call is wrapped by an ExecutionException and is popping up to the caller". I am sorry that I didn't get this.

Comment: @Jaraws, it throws a `new ExecutionException(yourActualException)` to the thread where you called `get` from. Then you call fetch `yourActualException` by `exception.getCause()`

Comment: Hello @Andrew, if pool thread throws an exception then pool must run out of its only thread. As, it is not happening here then there must be some channel through which this pool thread must be passing out its exception to the main thread and returning back to its pool.

Comment: @Jaraws, a thread pool never throws an exception, your task may throw it

Comment: @Jaraws, it's actually happening here, you are catching an `Exception` (including an `ExecutionException`), there will be a `RuntimeException` you have thrown from `call`

Comment: @Jaraws, an executor service/ a worker / a thread doesn't fail because of your exception happened there

Comment: Hello Andrew, Thanks for your replies. After going through several blogs, your answers and some code writings I got to know that if an exception arises during the execution of Callable, pool thread simply sets the variable "private Throwable exception;" of class FutureTask and returns back to its pool. And when get() is invoked over this FutureTask instance(which is an implementation of Future interface) from the main thread, it wraps the exception set by the pool thread inside ExecutionException and returns it back to the caller. Please correct me if I have misunderstood something. Thanks